# Sitecore 8.2.0 Unicorn 3.3 Items sync Issue [Error: Cannot perform initial serialization]

Tags: sitecore, unicorn, sitecore-habitat

I have followed steps mentioned [here](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/wiki/01-Getting-Started), but unable to sync items to local sitecore instance

[Sitecore Unicorn Sync Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7ygr.png)

Gulp Config:

```
var instanceRoot = "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\SC82";

websiteRoot= instanceRoot + "\\Website";
```

habitat Dev settings:

```
<sc.variable name="sourceFolder" value="C:\Users\Habitat-master\src" />
<sc.variable name="rootHostName" value="SC82" />
```

Publishing Targets:

```
<publishUrl>http://SC82</publishUrl>
```

Predicate Config:

`<predicate type="Unicorn.Predicates.SerializationPresetPredicate, Unicorn" singleInstance="true">
          <include database="master" path="/sitecore/content">
            <exclude path="/sitecore/content/" />
          </include>
          <include name="Home" database="master" path="/sitecore/layout/Controllers/Home" />
          <include name="Layout.Layouts" database="master" path="/sitecore/layout/Layouts/" />
          <include name="Layout.Models" database="master" path="/sitecore/layout/Models/" />
          <include name="Layout.PlaceholderSettings" database="master" path="/sitecore/layout/Placeholder Settings/" />
          <include name="Layout.Renderings.Project" database="master" path="/sitecore/layout/Renderings/" />
          <include name="System.Dictionary.Project" database="master" path="/sitecore/system/Dictionary/" />
          <include name="System.Languages" database="master" path="/sitecore/system/Languages" />
          <include name="System.Workflows" database="master" path="/sitecore/system/Workflows" />
          <include name="Templates.Project" database="master" path="/sitecore/templates/" />
          <include name="System.HtmlEditorProfiles" database="core" path="/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/" />
        </predicate>`

Error:
Cannot perform initial serialization because the predicate configuration is including item paths which do not exist in the database.

Can someone help on this issue?. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you run the default task in "Task Runner explorer"? http://imgur.com/a/vhXAO

Comment: Yes. Everything went well till 5th Task (Sync Unicorn). Logs it could see ["Unable to resolve serialized item for included root path master:/sitecore/system/Settings/Feature. The item does not exist in Serialization File System Data Store. It has been skipped. Perhaps you need to perform an initial serialization from the control panel?".

Comment: have you changed rootHostName in \Project\Common\code\App_Config\Include\Project\common.website.config?

Comment: I have tried to update root hostname also but same issue appears. Any other settings need to be checked?

Comment: There may be other helpful information here: http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3450/sitecore-habitat-gulp-is-not-running-sync-unicorn-task-and-neither-giving-any

Answer (score 0):

Latest code and in detailed steps are updated [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/set-up-sitecore-habitat-demo-site-30-minutes-yanbin-liu?trkInfo=VSRPsearchId%3A151389491481754695059%2CVSRPtargetId%3A6186751711420362752%2CVSRPcmpt%3Aprimary&trk=vsrp_influencer_content_res_name) :)

worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Manully run following unicorn sync url to see what's error you'll get. 
**{Your local host url}/unicorn.aspx?verb=Sync&configuration=&skipTransparentConfigs=0**

Also, make sure install the "**Web Forms for Marketers 8.2**" because Habitat uses it.